# Remove the greeting message from Git Bash "Welcome to Git" "Run 'git help git' to display the help index."

Tags: window, git-shell

Is it possible to remove the greeting message that Git Bash on Windows show every time I launch it?

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.1.2-preview20130201)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a search and found the text loads from this file `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\motd"`